# Statement (\STATE) indentation in Algorithmic package

Tags: formatting, indentation, memoir, algorithmic

I have the following code,

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of Algorithms}
\newlistof{listofalgorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmname}
\newfloat{algorithm}{loa}{\algorithmname}
\newfixedcaption{\falgcaption}{algorithm}
\newlistentry{algorithm}{loa}{0}  

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

\newpage
\chapter{Example Chapter}
\section{Example Section}
\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
\caption{An example algorithm}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\ENSURE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\STATE Statement 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. \COMMENT{This is a comment}
\REPEAT
\STATE Statement 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\STATE Statement 3:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\FOR{$i=0$ to $k$}
\STATE Statement 4:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\STATE Statement 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\ENDFOR
\UNTIL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\STATE Statement 6: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor cursus, felis lectus. 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This typeset as follows,

[image: Noindent]

As my pseudo code statements are relatively long, I would like the `\STATE` section (Statement 1...Statement 6) to have a slight hanging indentation as the `\REQUIRE` sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `memoir` class, only the `algormithmic` package.

The internal command controlling the printing commands like `\STATE` is `\ALC@it`.  This command is defined locally in each `algorithmic` environment.  The `\STATE` is just an `\item` in a list, but with some adjustments. The change one wants to make to this command is to add a `\parshape` just after the call to `\item`.  In this case the approrpiate `\parshape` is

```
\parshape 2 \dimexpr\ALC@tlm+\labelwidth\relax
\dimexpr\textwidth-\ALC@tlm-\labelwidth\relax 
\dimexpr\ALC@tlm+\labelwidth+\continueindent\relax
\dimexpr\textwidth-\ALC@tlm-\labelwidth-\continueindent\relax
```

`\ALC@tlm` essentially holds the current left indentation, but needs to be corrected by `\labelwidth`.  The command `\parshape n a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 ...` means that the first line will have left margin `a_1` and length `b_1` etc.  The `n`th specification applies to each of the remaining lines in the paragraph.  So to flushright margins, `b_k` has to be `\textwidth - a_k`.  I have introduced a new length `\continueindent`; in the code below it is initially set to `\algorithmicindent`, but you might want to choose a different value.

Ideally one would want to just patch the definition of the `algorithmic` environment, but unfortunately `etoolbox` reports that it can't do this.  So the code below copies the (long) definition from `algorithmic.sty` and just modifies the definition of `\ALC@it`, see the lines after the commend `%% Added three lines here %%`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of Algorithms}
\newlistof{listofalgorithms}{loa}{\listalgorithmname}
\newfloat{algorithm}{loa}{\algorithmname}
\newfixedcaption{\falgcaption}{algorithm}
\newlistentry{algorithm}{loa}{0}  

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\continueindent}
\setlength{\continueindent}{\algorithmicindent}
\renewenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{
\setcounter{ALC@depth}{\@listdepth}%
\let\@listdepth\c@ALC@depth%
\let\@item\ALC@item%
  \newcommand{\ALC@lno}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
{{\ALC@linenosize \arabic{ALC@line}\ALC@linenodelimiter}}{}%
}
\let\@listii\@listi
\let\@listiii\@listi
\let\@listiv\@listi
\let\@listv\@listi
\let\@listvi\@listi
\let\@listvii\@listi
  \newenvironment{ALC@g}{
    \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{ \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@
    \listparindent\z@ \rightmargin\z@
    \topsep\z@ \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@\parsep\z@
    \leftmargin \algorithmicindent%1em
    \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}
    }
  }
  {\end{list}}
  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{%
    \stepcounter{ALC@rem}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}%
    \stepcounter{ALC@line}%
    \refstepcounter{ALC@unique}%
    \item\def\@currentlabel{\theALC@line}%
    %% Added four lines here %%
    \parshape 2 \dimexpr\ALC@tlm+\labelwidth\relax
    \dimexpr\textwidth-\ALC@tlm-\labelwidth\relax 
    \dimexpr\ALC@tlm+\labelwidth+\continueindent\relax
    \dimexpr\textwidth-\ALC@tlm-\labelwidth-\continueindent\relax
    %% End of added material
  }
  \newcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{default}}%
{}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}
  \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}
  \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}
  \newcommand{\PRINT}{\ALC@it\algorithmicprint{} \ }
  \newcommand{\RETURN}{\ALC@it\algorithmicreturn{} \ }
  \newcommand{\TRUE}{\algorithmictrue{}}
  \newcommand{\FALSE}{\algorithmicfalse{}}
  \newcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand{} }
  \newcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor{} }
  \newcommand{\XOR}{\algorithmicxor{} }
  \newcommand{\NOT}{\algorithmicnot{} }
  \newcommand{\TO}{\algorithmicto{} }
  \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}
  \newcommand{\STMT}{\ALC@it}
  \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@inputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@outputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@globals}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@body}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
  \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}
  \newcommand{\INPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicinputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@inputs}}
  \newcommand{\ENDINPUTS}{\end{ALC@inputs}}
  \newcommand{\OUTPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicoutputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@outputs}}
  \newcommand{\ENDOUTPUTS}{\end{ALC@outputs}}
  \newcommand{\GLOBALS}{\ALC@it\algorithmicglobals\ }
  \newcommand{\BODY}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicbody\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@body}}
  \newcommand{\ENDBODY}{\end{ALC@body}}
  \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\ELSIF}[2][default]%
{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
  \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\FORALL}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
  \newcommand{\WHILE}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicwhile\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}
  \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}
  \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat%
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}
  \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}
  }{
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}
  }
  \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}
  \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}\setcounter{ALC@line}{0}%
    \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@%
    \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
    \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
  {\labelwidth 0.5em }
  {\labelwidth  1.2em }
\leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
    \ALC@tlm\labelsep
  }
}
{\end{list}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example Chapter}
\section{Example Section}
\begin{algorithm}[htbp]
\caption{An example algorithm}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor
cursus, felis lectus.  
\ENSURE Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor
cursus, felis lectus.  
\STATE Statement 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor
cursus, felis lectus. \COMMENT{This is a comment}
\REPEAT
\STATE Statement 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor
cursus, felis lectus.  
\STATE Statement 3:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat
quis tempor cursus, felis lectus.  
\FOR{$i=0$ to $k$}
\STATE Statement 4:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat
quis tempor cursus, felis lectus.  
\STATE Statement 5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor
cursus, felis lectus.  
\ENDFOR
\UNTIL{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\STATE Statement 6: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit. Integer lobortis luctus tincidunt. Ut commodo, erat quis tempor
cursus, felis lectus.  
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```